# How to pass value dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table which has the column name "12" Instead of that value I want to pass it dynamically and for that I have a created item "P_Itm_val" see attached image for reference.

```
$('td[headers = "12"]').each(function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"whitesmoke"});  
    $(this).css({"color":"green"});
    $(this).css({"font-weight":"bold"});
  });
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvhfu.png)

Comment: Ask question clearly with input and out samples.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the value there instead of "10"

```
 $('td[headers = P_Itm_val]').each(function() {
     $(this).css({"background-color":"whitesmoke"});  
     $(this).css({"color":"green"});
     $(this).css({"font-weight":"bold"});
 });
```

If that doesn't work, try appending the value into the call

```
 $('td[headers = "'+P_Itm_val+'"]').each(function() {
     $(this).css({"background-color":"whitesmoke"});  
     $(this).css({"color":"green"});
     $(this).css({"font-weight":"bold"});
 });
```

I'm not quite sure what I did for this however, I've done something similar to this.

Comment: both of them are not working

Comment: I've updated the 2nd one to have double quotes around it.  I'm assuming P_Itm_val is a string but has a number in it.

Comment: P_Itm_val is a page item and value in that has a string datatype

Comment: What value is in it?  Is it a number?

Comment: Yes it has a number but string datatype

Comment: I've updated the 2nd solution.  Try that and see what happens.  I've added double quotes around it so it would have "10" around it if 10 were the value in P_Itm_val.

Comment: refer the attached image.. if I hardcode value it is working fine but I want to change the value dynamically

Comment: still not working

Comment: Looking at my sources if it is a string you should be able to do this
$('#' + elementId)
That isn't the solution however you get the idea.

Comment: The concatenation solution looks fine. Perhaps add a debug statement to check the value of P_Itm_val